# How to get HTML file contents as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to get the contents of an HTML file in JavaScript as a string.

Wrote such code, but does not work, displays an error: Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'

How ca i fix it, or are there other ways to read HTML file in JavaScript?

```
function getFile(U) {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var X = new XMLHttpRequest();
    X.open('GET', U, false);
    X.send();
  return X.responseText;
}

const f = getFile('index.html');

const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    response.end(f);
}).listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Server work');
});
```

Comment: It's [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), but you can also use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead.

Comment: Can you post your Code? How else should we find ther Error in it?

Comment: Please state clearly what you intend to do. Also, share your code which is showing the error

Comment: Is this a node.js question? If so, please tag appropriately.

Comment: You're trying to use `XMLHttpRequest` which only exists in the browser. While you're in NodeJs. Which doesn't know `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Is there such a function is JS to get HTML file in text format?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFile(U) {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var X = new XMLHttpRequest();
    X.open('GET', U, false);
    X.send();
  return X.responseText;
}

const f = getFile('index.html');

const http = require('http');

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    response.end(f);
}).listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Server work');
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting your code to an answer.